# Where in the database do I find channel_short_name

Tags: query, sql

I'm trying to write a custom SQL query like this:

```
{exp:query sql="
    SELECT channel_short_name
    FROM what_table_is_it_in
    WHERE entry_id = '{embed:entry_id}'"
}
{channel_short_name}
{/exp:query}
```

It's inside an embed template with an entry_id passed in as {embed:entry_id}. I just need it to output the channel short name for that channel of that entry.

What database table is this in? I can't find it!

I'm trying to replicate the example at the very bottom of this page: http://www.solspace.com/docs/rating/entries/ except I want to get channel_short_name instead of entry title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Channel titles are stored in the (exp_)channels table in the channel_name column, so you'll have to do a join to get the information you need.

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT c.channel_name as channel_shortname FROM exp_channels as c LEFT JOIN exp_channel_titles as ct on c.channel_id = ct.channel_id WHERE ct.entry_id = '14'"}
    {channel_shortname}
{/exp:query}
```

In this case, I would use a regular channel entries loop instead of a query loop. I don't think it would produce much more queries if you disable everything.

```
{exp:channel:entries disable="categories|category_fields|custom_fields|member_data|pagination" entry_id="{embed:entry_id}" limit="1" dynamic="no"}
    {channel_short_name}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Thanks. Don't know why I didn't think of that ;-)

Comment: Added the query you would need. Try running both and choose the least expensive solution.

Comment: When I use stash, I generally use stash embeds with process="start" (essentially the same as a snippet). Since that is processed first, I can use all the variables from the father template directly.